# How to pass login inputs dynamically through JSON file in C# selenium?

Tags: c#, json, selenium

I have created automation script to test WEB UI using selenium C#. I dont want to hardcode the login details and want to send those values through JSON input. How do I convert Json inputs in C#.

```
 IWebDriver webdriver = new ChromeDriver(@"D:\Selenium\Chrome_90V");
        Loginpage LoginP = new Loginpage(webdriver);
        Homepage homep = new Homepage(webdriver);
        DataJson Js = new DataJson();
        
        webdriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://login.microsoftonline.com");
        //timewait
        TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
        webdriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = timeSpan;
        //emailidinput
        LoginP.setemail("**abcdefgh@gmail.com**");
        LoginP.clicknext();
```

How do I tell my code to use JSON inputs through class.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution for this and would like to post it here, if someone else is looking for this.

> First create Json file in and put the values in array as:
> { "key":"value";
> "email": "abcedfgh@gmail.com";}

> Next create a new Cs file and convert json file to Csharp
> class Login
> {
> public string Key{ get; set; }
> public string email { get; set; }
> }

> next create a new Cs file to parse the data
> class DataSourceParser
> {
> public static Login populateLogin()
> {
> string Loginjson = File.ReadAllText(@"");
> Login login = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Loginjson);
> return login;
> }
> }

Now update your test script mentioned in my query as:
Login login =  DataSourceParser. PopulateLogin();
instead of
"DataJson Js = new DataJson();"

verify all string details appears at **login**.

> instead of providing mailid use    LoginP.setemail**(login.emailid);**